# SQLite save and load image iOS

Tags: ios, image, sqlite

I'm trying to save the Image and Load it in a tableView, for saving in my SQLite file I do this :

```
-(void)InsertRecords:(NSData *)pic{
..... // Open my SQLite file
NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO myMovies (movieImage) VALUES (\"%@\")", pic];
...
const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
...
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [pic bytes], [pic length], NULL);
...
```

Which pic is a NSData and i got NSLog of it. and gave me the codes. Also for loading I used this code :

```
int length = sqlite3_column_bytes(sqlStatement, 1);
MyMovie.image = [NSData dataWithBytes:sqlite3_column_blob(sqlStatement, 1) length:length];
```

and NSLoged from it and it had the similar structure of the NSData but with different data ! It completely changed ! Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

`sqlite3_bind_blob` binds to a parameter, but your insert statement does not actually have a parameter. (You should have checked its return value for errors.)

What you insert statement has is the picture formatted as string, which will break for any non-ASCII bytes.

Comment: Actually, `%@` will use whatever is returned by `-description`, which (for NSData) is a hexdump of the data surrounded by <>.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char *insert_stmt = [@"INSERT INTO myMovies (movieImage) VALUES (?)" UTF8String];
...
sqlite3_bind_blob(statement, 1, [pic bytes], [pic length], SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but it doesn't work, this time there is no output at all ! :/